# Delete user inputted word in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

so basic and begginner question here - how to delete specific (in my case third) word which user has inputted in input dialog box?
Help really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask]. Remember **SO is not a free code service!**

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you are asking how to delete a word from the dialog box itself (so that a user can see that the word has been deleted), or how to get the input string and then remove the third word from that. Your question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Try `input_text.split(" ")` which splits the text into its spearate words.

Then recompose the string from the returned array, leaving out the 3rd element.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
String str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13";
String parts[] = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    if ((i+1)%3 != 0) {
       sb.append(parts[i]);
       sb.append(" ");
    }
} 
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

The output the input without every third word (separated with `" "`).

> 1 2 4 5 7 8 10 11 13

The way how to do that.
- First you split your string with delimiter `" "` with `str.split(" ")` and sending it to an array of String.
- Then you loop all words skip every third word `if ((i+1)%3 != 0)`.
- You write them to `StringBuilder` with `sb.append(..)` and dont forget for another space `" "`.
- You get the final string from `StringBuilder`. You concatenate Strings with this class instead of `str = str1 + str2` (not the correct way).